# XML validation : prefix expected without necessity?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate my the following XML document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xrm:plugin xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm testplugin.xsd" xmlns:tech="http://www.moss.fr/2011/moteur-xrm" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:attribut="http://www.moss.fr/2012/attribut" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mcd="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:xrm="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" xmlns:variable="http://www.moss.fr/2012/variable" xmlns:doc="http://www.moss.fr/2011/documentation" xmlns:mtf2xsd="http://www.moss.fr/2010/mtf2xsd" xmlns:conv="http://www.moss.fr2010/conversion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:info="http://www.moss.fr/2011/information" xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema">
<xrm:mapping occurs="xrm:mapping">
  <SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA xmlns=""
                                 info:obligatoire="true"
                                 occurs="/grappe"
                                 info:contexte="/grappe">
  </SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA>
 </xrm:mapping>
</xrm:plugin>
```

I'm using this main schema **testplugin.xsd** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xrm="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns:metier="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"  targetNamespace="http://www.moss.fr/2011/connecteur_xrm" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" >
 <xsd:import namespace="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm"  schemaLocation="balisesXrm.xsd" />
 <xsd:import namespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" schemaLocation="metier1.xsd"/>

<xsd:complexType name="mapping">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element ref="metier:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

 <xsd:element name="plugin">
  <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="mapping" type="xrm:mapping"/>
     </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

With the import **metier1.xsd** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:nr0="http://NamespaceTest.com/balisesXrm" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:SCCOAMCD="urn:SCCOA-schemaInfo" xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" xmlns:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema" version="3.2.1ec">

  <xsd:element name="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>


 <xsd:complexType name="type_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA">

   <xsd:sequence>

     <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Entities" type="SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA:type_Data_SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA"/>

   </xsd:sequence>

  <xsd:attributeGroup ref="attributsXrm"/>
 </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:attributeGroup name="attributsXrm">
  <xsd:attribute name="group-by"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="id"/>
  <xsd:attribute name="occurs"/>
</xsd:attributeGroup>

</xsd:schema>
```

I have the following error when I try to validate my XML :

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA'. One of {"urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema":SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA} is expected.

I have tried to change in my XML document the `xmlns="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"` by `xmlns:s="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"` and add to `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` the prefix `s:` and it works. 
But I can't understand why i have to put a prefix in this situation. Actually i don't want to modify my XML document but rather my XSD if it is possible.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `xmlns=""` attribute on the `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` tag in your XML, it sets the tag in the empty namespace.

Without it, the `xmlns` specified on your `xrm:plugin` tag, the expected `urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema`, will correctly be taken into account for your `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` tag.

It seems like a bad idea to modify the XSD rather than the XML, but if you really need to then you will need to have your XSD define the `SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA` element in the empty namespace, which you could do by removing the `targetNamespace="urn:SBEGestionZonesAeriennesSYSCA-schema"` attribute on your metier1.xsd's root and updating the reference to your element in the testplugin.xsd.